# Page scroll display

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I am trying to recreate an interactive image gallery where the user clicks on an image and that image expands in order for the user to see it bigger than it was. Everything runs smoothly but as soon as I press an image and it expands, the page becomes a bit bigger and the background image moves a bit, giving the user the opportunity to scroll up and down, left and right. I don't like that for aesthetic reasons and the movement of the background image is a bit weird for my taste. I figure that it has something to do with the margin attribute of the container div where the expanded image is displayed because I tested the margin setting it to very high numbers and it does give a lot of space at the bottom of the image when the numbers are high. I am giving you the code:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="1st project\labeleven.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        <img src="1st project\labfive.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="1st project\labsix.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        <img src="1st project\labseven.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="1st project\labtwo.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        <img src="1st project\labeight.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="1st project\labnine.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        <img src="1st project\labten.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="1st project\labthree.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        <img src="1st project\labfour.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <img id="expandedImg" style="width:560">
    <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    function myFunction(imgs) {
        var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
        var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
        expandImg.src = imgs.src;
        imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
        expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

CSS

```
/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 170;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: -15px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
    opacity: 0.8; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top:2px;
}

.column img:hover {     
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container (positioning is needed to position the close button and the text) */
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    left: 376px;
    top: -230px;
}

/* Closable button inside the image */
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 500px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

PS: I did use the code from the webpage of w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I think for aesthetic reasons you'd like to use a modal to open each image in the foreground. Try this link here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp where you'll get the gist of modals also on w3 schools.

Explanation: 
The reason everything becomes ugly when you click the image is that 100% means whatever attributes the image has as dimensions (which may not even be identical). You could try giving fixed pixels instead of percentages, but that would make it unresponsive. You could use [vw and vh](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) which takes into consideration the viewport width and height, but the elegant solution (for an image gallery) would be to use modals.

LATER EDIT: My skin crawls when I see negative values in positioning absolute. It's usually frowned upon, so make sure [you REALLY understand them](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) when using.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the negative values. I will read the relevant article! As I said to @dislick above, I do not want to display the photos in foreground, though it's a nice alternative which I will keep in mind.

Comment: then I guess you should use the other things I suggested. Just keep in mind that when you re-render DOM with innerHTML it's really not best practice nor good standards.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your CSS a bit, try this out:

```
/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 170;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: -15px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
    opacity: 0.8; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top:2px;
}

.column img:hover {     
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container (positioning is needed to position the close button and the text) */
.container {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     text-align: center;
}

#expandedImg {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The most important changes are at the bottom.

Comment: I will keep that as an alternative because it's quite nice. But other than that, I would like to find a solution at the current problem so I can have two option for the display of the images. Thank you a lot anyway!!